# How to Create Model for Nested JSON where There is a List of JSON Inside Nested JSON?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a structure of JSON response like code below (example):

```
{
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Baburiki",
        "jutsu_variant": [
          {
            "jutsu_name": "wind release",
            "damage": 1200,
          },
        ], 
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Zee",
        "jutsu_variant": [
          {
            "jutsu_name": "wind release",
            "damage": 1200,
          },
          {
            "jutsu_name": "kage bunshin",
            "damage": 2000,
          },
        ], 
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

There is a list of JSON on the `items` key and in that key, there is another list of JSON on the `jutsu_variant` key.

I have created a class model to store the JSON response like the following code

```
class ShinobiData {
  int? id;
  String? shinobiName;
  JutsuVariant? jutsuVariant;

  ShinobiData({
    this.id,
    this.shinobiName,
    this.jutsuVariant,
  });

  factory ShinobiData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ShinobiData(
      id: json['id'],
      shinobiName: json['name'],
      jutsuVariant: json['jutsu_variant'],
    );
  }
}

class JutsuVariant {
  String? jutsuName;
  int? jutsuDamage;

  JutsuVariant({this.jutsuName, this.jutsuDamage});

  factory JutsuVariant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return JutsuVariant(
      jutsuName: json['jutsu_name'],
      jutsuDamage: json['damage'],
    );
  }
}
```

The model is working fine if there is no `list` on the `jutsu_variant` key.

This is my class for getting the API response of POST requests. (created with provider state management)

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:learning_api/model/shinobi_model.dart';

class CatalogResponse with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, dynamic> _map = {};
  bool _error = false;
  String _errorMessage = '';
  List<ShinobiData> _shinobis = [];

  Map<String, dynamic> get map => _map;

  List<ShinobiData> get shinobis => _shinobis;

  bool get error => _error;

  String get errorMessage => _errorMessage;

  Future<void> get fetchData async {
    var _finalBody = {
      'page': 1,
      'items_per_page': 5,
    };

    String _body = const JsonEncoder().convert(_finalBody);

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://***/url'),
      body: _body,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      try {
        _map = (jsonDecode(response.body))['data'];
        List<dynamic> _listShinobi = (_map)['items'];

        // this loop will add each item in the items key 
        for (int i = 0; i < _listShinobi.length; i++)
          _shinobis.add(CatalogData.fromJson(_listItem[i]));

        _error = false;
      } catch (e) {
        _error = true;
        _errorMessage = e.toString();
        _map = {};
        _catalogs = [];
      }
    } else {
      _error = true;
      _errorMessage = "Error: It would be your internet connection";
      _map = {};
      _catalogs = [];
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void initialValues() {
    _map = {};
    _catalogs = [];
    _error = false;
    _errorMessage = "";
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The above code works perfectly for `name` and `id` key calling. But the problem occurs when calling the `jutsu_variant` key. What should I do to be able to call the value of the `jutsu_name` and the `damage` key that is in the `jutsu_variant` key?

Cases like this do not exist in any tutorial resources. Maybe your answer will be very valuable in the future. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

in your `ShinobiData` class
you should use `List<JutsuVariant>` instead of  `JutsuVariant`

you can use [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) or even [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) to generate these files automatically for you

Answer (score 0):

This IDE plugin [JosnToDart](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12562-jsontodart-json-to-dart-/) is very convenience for me. It can generate response model just paste json to this. More we can choose nullable or not option when generate.